# How to exclude a subfolder from an FTP upload when using WinSCP in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, ftp, winscp

I create a batch file to upload the file from my local server to the remote server using WinSCP

Here is my code.

```
@echo off

"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
  /log="C:\log\WinSCP.log" /ini=nul ^
  /command ^
    "open s3://USername:PAssword@s3.amazonaws.com/" ^
    "lcd E:\Backups" ^
    "cd /backup/Backup/Config" ^
    "put LiveMainTrade" ^
    "exit"

set WINSCP_RESULT=%ERRORLEVEL%
if %WINSCP_RESULT% equ 0 (
  echo Success
) else (
  echo Error
)

exit /b %WINSCP_RESULT%
```

Under the `LiveMainTrade` Folder, I have `A`, `B`, and `C` three folders. I want to exclude the folder `A`, and only upload the folders `B` and `C`.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`-filemask` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put#filemask) to exclude the subfolder, like:

```
    "put -filemask=|C\ LiveMainTrade" ^
```

See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#directory